# Jquery Datatable Extend Editor Delete Button Behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, editor

I started using jquery datatables with editor. I've got a basic table with an add and delete button.

The delete button provides a small dialog with a preview of the selected data. If I submit the dialog the selected row is deleted from the table.

But how is it possible to send an ajax to my backend after submitting the dialog button?

[image]

My code right now looks like:

```
        $('table').DataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
            "zeroRecords": "Keine Einträge gefunden",
            "info": "Seite _PAGE_ von _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "Keine Einträge vorhanden",
            "infoFiltered": "(_MAX_ Einträge gesamt)",
            "search": "Suche:",
            "paginate": {
                "first":      "erste",
                "last":       "letzte",
                "next":       "nächste",
                "previous":   "vorherige"
            }
        },
        dom: 'Bfrtip',        // Needs button container
        select: 'single',
        responsive: true,
        altEditor: true,     // Enable altEditor
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Add',
                name: 'add',        // do not change name
            },
            {
                extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
                text: 'Bearbeiten',
                name: 'edit'        // do not change name
            },
            {
                extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
                text: 'Löschen',
                name: 'delete',      // do not change name
            },
        ],
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to send it to the server? You can make an API submit() call:

```
editor
    .create( false )
    .set( 'name', 'Airi' )
    .set( 'position', 'Accountant' )
    .set( 'office', 'Tokyo')
    .submit();
```

You could tie this to any number of events: [remove()](https://editor.datatables.net/reference/event/remove), [preRemove()](https://editor.datatables.net/reference/event/preRemove) or [postRemove()](https://editor.datatables.net/reference/event/postRemove) would be good candidates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onAddRow, onEditRow and onDeleteRow events. In the events, you can write code to call ajax. Check the below example

```
      onAddRow: function (datatable, rowdata, success, error) {
        //add item to the rowdata 
        rowdata["make_order"] = id;
        rowdata["production_status"] = 3 // Not started
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
          },
          type: "POST",
          data: rowdata,
          success: success,
          error: error,
        });
      },
      onDeleteRow: function (datatable, rowdata, success, error) {
        $.ajax({
          url: url + rowdata.id + "/",
          headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
          },
          type: "DELETE",
          data: rowdata,
          success: success,
          error: error,
        });
      },
      onEditRow: function (datatable, rowdata, success, error) {
        //add item to the rowdata 
        rowdata["make_order"] = id;
        $.ajax({
          url: url + rowdata.id + "/",
          headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
          },
          type: "PUT",
          data: rowdata,
          success: success,
          error: error,
        });
```